# Trying to use forEach to count occurrences in 2D array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, foreach

I'm trying to get familiar with arrow functions and in this case the ability to count the *number of occurrences* of a string within a 2D array. This is what I have so far:

**GOAL**
Count the number of occurrences of 'cat' in a 2D array

**Array**

> var arr = [
> ['mammal','dog','fur'],
> ['mammal','cat','fur'],
> ['mammal','cat','fur'],
> ['fish','trout','scales']
> ];

**Current code using forEach**

```
  var count = arr.map(outer => outer.forEach(str => {
    if(str == 'cat') {
    count + 1;}
     }));

  return console.log(count.length);
```

**ACTUAL RESULT**

> Info  4

**DESIRED RESULT**

> Info 2

As I mentioned, I'm still new to custom functions so any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some.. more efficient solutions.

`.map()` isn't necessarily the strongest Array Method to use here, as we don't need to clone and modify the original array as we iterate through the data. We're just looking counting occurances.

---

Using `.reduce()`:

```
const count = arr.reduce((acc, row) => {

    row.forEach((item) => {
      if (item === `cat`) acc++
    })

    return acc

}, 0)
```

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

---

Using `.flatMap()` and `.filter()`:

```
const count = arr.flatMap((row) => row).filter((item) => item === `cat`).length
```

- [Array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

---

Learn More:

[Array Methods](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/library/array)